# Is there a quick way to create a new instance of a Dart class from an existing object?

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically wondering if there is a quick way other than creating a method to create a new class instance from itself so the example below would print 9, not 15.

```html
void main() {
  
  final classOne = SomeClass(mutableString: 'Hello', mutableInt: 9); 
  
  final classTwo = classOne; 
  
  classTwo.mutableInt = 15; 
  
  print(classOne.mutableInt); 
  
}


class SomeClass {
  
  SomeClass({required this.mutableString, required this.mutableInt}); 
  
  String mutableString; 
  int mutableInt; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method in the class which retuns the same object.
For example :
I am ading copyWith method in SomeClass

```
class SomeClass {
  SomeClass({required this.mutableString, required this.mutableInt});

  String mutableString;
  int mutableInt;

  SomeClass copyWith({int? mutableInt}) {
    return SomeClass(
      mutableString: this.mutableString,
      mutableInt: mutableInt ?? this.mutableInt,
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can use the method as :

```
void main() {
  
  final classOne = SomeClass(mutableString: 'Hello', mutableInt: 9); 
  
  final classTwo = classOne.copyWith(mutableInt:15);; 
  
  print(classOne.mutableInt); 
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@anoncgain solution is correct up-to an extent.

You can also do the same as

```
class SomeClass {
  //...other code ....
  String? mutableString; //make your params nullable
  int? mutableInt; 
  
  //declare a named constructor to copp the existing object value.
  SomeClass.copy(SomeClass object){
    mutableString = object.mutableString;
    mutableInt = object.mutableInt;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
final classTwo = SomeClass.copy(classOne);
//it will copy the values to the newly created object 
//rather then storing the reference of the object
```